# Power BI Security Data Storage

Tags: backup, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

1. The data that I can find in the DATASETS section in PowerBI Service, where is it stored?
2. Do there exist back-ups of my reports and dashboard in PowerBI Service and where are they stored? And what data is in these files?
3. If I have PowerBI Embedded, where is my data stored and what data is actually being stored?
4. What is the relationship between PowerBI and Office365?

Answer (score 0):

1. The datasets in PowerBI Service is stored in PowerBI Cloud.
2. The reports that you upload are stored in PowerBI Cloud Service. However, there are no back-ups of those reports.
3. You can use the Embedding feature of PowerBI to embed reports in your application. PowerBI embeds reports as an iframe in your application. For more details refer this link: [PowerBI Embedding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedding)
4. Previously there was an admin portal for PowerBI Office 365. However, this has been removed now. You can read more about it here :[PowerBI Office 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-o365portal-retired)